# JAXB JSON array not in object

Tags: arrays, json, jaxb

I would like to know how I can use JAXB to consume and produce a JSON array from a List without being included in an object:

```
[ "element1", "element2", "element3"]
```

Currently I have being only able to do so by including it in an object:

```
{ "elements" : [ "element1", "element2", "element3"] }
```

The code used is more or less the one below.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "elements")
public class ElementListSerializerHelper
    @XmlElement(name = "elements")
    @JsonProperty(value = "elements")
    public List<String> list;

    public ElementsListSerializerHelper() {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public ElementsListSerializerHelper(List<String> list) {
        this.list = new ArrayList<String>(list);
    }
}
```

Any help is more than welcome. The option I'm also thinking is generating/parsing a string based on jackson library.